# Virtual Machine Manager/Network Interfaces

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Ubunu 21.10

I expect to have Virtual Machine Manager/Network Interfaces tab and Network Boot (PXE) option when create a new VM andI do not.

Anybody knows how to turn on the Virtual Machine Manager/Connection
Details/Network Interfaces tab?
On my VMM the tab is missing as you can see below:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is how it looks in my Ubuntu 20.04. Could you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1371787/edit) and explain more of what you are trying to do and what you expect to see?

Comment: "This is how it looks" on yours machine, should have a link or something, just asking?

Comment: By "this" I mean the screenshots in your question.

Comment: so, yours like mine

Comment: I don't see the problem. Maybe if you explain in words rather than adding more pictures someone can help.